# No header on first page of chapter

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2, pagestyle

I am using the scrpage2 package in my Latex-document to generate headers on each page. Now i get a header which says the name of the current chapter and an unterline.
This is my code:

```
\usepackage[plainheadsepline,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ihead[\sffamily \upshape \bfseries \headmark]{\sffamily \bfseries \upshape \headmark}

\chead[]{}

\ohead[]{}

\ifoot[]{}

\cfoot[]{}

\ofoot[\sffamily \pagemark]{\sffamily \pagemark}

\automark[]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}
```

I have already used the following line to get rid of the headers but then my pagenumbers dissappear

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Normally i should get just the pagenumbers with the next line, but with this i get the headers again

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: So if I understand well you want the page number in the footer and no header. Is that right ?

Comment: Just for your information, `scrpage2` is outdated and superseded by `scrlayer-scrpage`. Also, which `\documentclass` do you use?

Comment: Yes you did unterstand this right. My Documentclass is scrreprt.

Comment: Off-topic: It is recommended to use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1\baselineskip]{chapter}` or `\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1\baselineskip,runin=false]{chapter}` to set the skip below the chapter heading instead of redefining `\chapterheadendvskip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify that the plain pages should contain the `\headmark` as well by calling `\ihead[...]{...}` (the optional argument is the stuff that goes into plain. So if you don't want that just leave that out. If you additionally don't want the rule on the chapter pages, drop `plainheadsepline` from the package options (the following uses `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `scrpage2`)

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[plainheadsepline, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content

\ihead[]{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\headmark}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[]{}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\sffamily \pagemark]{\sffamily \pagemark}
\automark[]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image]